# Jordan normal form - Real matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Given the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} 7 &1 &2 &2 \\ 1 &4 &-1 &-1 \\ -2 &1 &5 &-1 \\ 1 &1 &2 &8 \end{pmatrix}$. I found its characteristic polynomium, which is $f(x) = (x-6)^4$, and I found this eigenvectors: $(-1,-1,1,0),(-1,-1,0,1)$. My questions are:

1. Am I right?
2. How can I do to find another matrix $C$ such that $\mathcal{J} = C^{-1}AC$, where $\mathcal{J} = \begin{pmatrix} 6 &1 &0 &0 \\ 0 &6 &0 &0 \\ 0 &0 &6 &1 \\ 0 &0 &0 &6 \end{pmatrix}$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: do you know how to get the minimal polynomial for the matrix $A$??

Comment: I think minimal polynomial is $m(x) = (x-4)^3$

Comment: Right, but you shouldn't only think, instead, you should be sure and explain why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B = A - 6 I$ 
$$
B=\pmatrix{  1&
 1&
 2&
 2\\
 1&
-2&
-1&
-1\\
-2&
 1&
-1&
-1\\
 1&
 1&
 2&
 2
}$$
Verify that $B^3=0$ but $B^2 \ne 0$. So it must have a jordon block of size $3$. So you will have one block of size 3 and the other of size 1, i.e of the form
$$
\pmatrix{  
 6&
 1& 0 &
 0\\
0&
6&
1&0\\
0&0&
 6&
0\\
 0&
 0&
 0&
 6
}$$

How to find the transformation matrix?

First find the eigenvectors by solving 
$$
B e = 0
$$
and you have already done it to get $e_1$ and $e_2$.
Now try and solve
$$
B e_3 = e_1$$
If this is not possible, try
$$
B e_3 = e_2$$
Only one of them is possible.

Next solve
$$
B e_4 = e_3
$$
Now the four vectors are the columns of $C$.

Note in all this it goes without saying that $e_i$ should not be zero.

**Sorry, I pulled a fast one on this**

In general, if you start with $e_1$ and $e_2$ you may not be able to get $e_3$. However, there is one linear combination of $e_1$ and $e_2$ that is in the column space of $B$. That is the one you want to use to get $e_3$. I.e. a vector in the intersection of the space spanned by columns of $B$ and the space spanned by $e_1$ and $e_2$.

Comment: the pseudo diagonalizing matrix $C$ follows from [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jordandecomposition+%7B%7B7%2C1%2C2%2C2%7D%2C%7B1%2C4%2C-1%2C-1%7D%2C%7B-2%2C1%2C5%2C-1%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C2%2C8%7D%7D]

Comment: Important to stress is that the matrix $C$ isn't unique

Comment: Any two eigenvectors are not enough. One of them has to be specialized. It is now official. I hate Jordon blocks :)

Comment: You need a total of 4 vectors. Two are eigenvectors, so the other two have to be generalized eigenvectors. That both have to come from the same base eigenvector follows from $B^2\neq0$ and $B^3=0$. So it says there is an invariant eigenspace of dimension 3 that is spanned by 1 eigenvector and its two generalized offsprings

Comment: No, the first two columns of $S$ in WA are ordinary eigenvalues (check it out). They just happen to be different than the one OP posted. Of the two, the second has the property of being in the column space of $A-6I$. So this eigenvector gives the next two columns of $S$. Please verify that first two columns of $S$ are indeed eigenvectors (hence the first to columns of the Jordon from are simple).